# log out from Oauth2 server AND from all clients

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We have a java web app, which contains a lot of wars. We have an Oauth2 server(written by us) and we will have a lot clients( around 8). All of this will be under the same domain. Except of this we have another app( running on completely different tomcat. There a Liferay is used). The idea is that that the user will use them as they are using one app and they should not see big difference.
This is way now what I need is that when I log out from one place in some way to say the oauth2 server and all other clients to log out, too.
Because for client should be : I already logged out why in some parts I'm still logged in?
Currently I'm not sure how to do it.
And to a lot of places I read that normally this is not the practice.
Can you give me hints and explain me from where I can start? Maybe to use Oauth2 in my case in not the best choice?

Comment: Silvia, what you want is called Single Sign On (SSO). There is an [OpenID Connect Session Management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) RFC that discusses how to implement it.

Comment: maybe this link can help: http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2

Comment: Thank you for the link, but there is no information how to log out in the way that we want.

Comment: @SilviaPetrova OAuth2 spec doesn't support it, so in general it is not possible. But depending on your implementation in some cases you could implement it. If your implementation uses tokens, which are always checked with an authorization server call/database call, you can change the implementation of this endpoint/database access. This is for example not possible for JWT.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can implement OAuth2 using JDBC Token Store from Spring Security. For this to work once user logs out, all client should invoke your Delete token API where you can remove the Access Token

```
    @FrameworkEndpoint
    public class RevokeTokenEndpoint {

        @Resource(name = "tokenServices")
        ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/oauth/token")
        @ResponseBody
        public void revokeToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

            //Delete the Token
        }
    }
```

Also, you should delete the refresh token.This way, the token would be invalidated once user logs-out and subsequent client can no longer use the same token